# Java change View from menu not working

Tags: java, swing

I usually don't need to ask Java questions, but I'm stuck more than ever on something now and I think I'm just missing something over and over again..

I have a JFrame application that has a JMenuBar. The items in the menubar have my class PageManager as their ActionListener. Debug shows this all works fine. The whole lot is initialized like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    UI ui = new UI();                       //The JFrame
    PageManager pm = new PageManager(ui);   //Menu ActionListener
    MenuBar mb = new MenuBar(pm);           //MenuBar
    ui.setJMenuBar(mb);
    ui.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
    ui.setVisible(true);
    ui.setPage(new Home().getPanel());      //a View
}
```

In the UI class, I have the following method:

```
    public void setPage(JPanel p) {
    System.out.println("Set page");
    this.remove(page);
    System.out.println("Removed");
    this.add(p);
    System.out.println("Added " + p);
}
```

The `ui.setPage(new Home().getPanel());` method call works fine. If I move it to the constructor of PageManager, it works too. If I replace it with `ui.setPage(new Preferences().getPanel());`, it works too. The Home and Preferences classes are Views that create a JPanel and return it using the getPanel method.

However, changing the page using the actionlistener doesn't seem to work. ALL System.out.println lines print fine, but the page isn't changed. I use this in PageManager:

```
private void changePage(String s, int i) {
    if(s.equals("P")) {
        //Program options
        System.out.println("program options");
        if(i == 1) {
            ui.setPage(pref.getPanel());
        }
    } else if(s.equals("C")) {
        //Connection options
    } else if(s.equals("A")) {
        //Add rule
    }
}
```

(ActionListener picks up the event, checks the source and calls changePage with it).

Thing is, everything runs and seems to work fine according to console output, but the page won't change whatever I do (including small modifications).

Any help would be greatly appreceated!!!

Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: Do check the sample program I had attached, try to put revalidate() and repaint() in comment, and the changes wont' be visible, but if you will not Comment them out, then changes will be realized on the said JFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally to achieve such behaviour the easier way out is the use of [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

And Moreover, once you add a new panel to already existing JFrame, by removing the old one, try to `revalidate()` and `repaint()`, so that the new addition can be realized.

If your JDK is 1.6 or below then revalidate on frame wont' work, instead use `frameObject.getRootPane().revalidate();`

```
revalidate() on JFrame is directly used with JDK 7+
```

Here is one sample code snippet to help your cause, with JMenuBar added to it :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame
{
    public FrameTest()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);        

        final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("MENU 1");
        JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("MENU 2");
        JMenu menu3 = new JMenu("MENU 3");


        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("CHANGE PANELS");     
        JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("MENU ITEM 2");
        JMenuItem menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("MENU ITEM 3");
        menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (panel1.isShowing())
                {
                    remove(panel1);
                    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                else if (panel2.isShowing())
                {
                    remove(panel2);
                    add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                // for getRootPane().revalidate();
                revalidate(); // For JDK 7+
                repaint();
            }
        });

        menu1.add(menuItem1);
        menu2.add(menuItem2);
        menu3.add(menuItem3);

        menuBar.add(menu1);
        menuBar.add(menu2);
        menuBar.add(menu3);

        JButton button = new JButton("CHANGE");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (panel1.isShowing())
                {
                    remove(panel1);
                    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                else if (panel2.isShowing())
                {
                    remove(panel2);
                    add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                // for getRootPane().revalidate();
                revalidate(); // For JDK 7+
                repaint();
            }
        });

        add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new FrameTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I have several reasons why I want to use MenuBar so I really want to try stick with that.

I use JDK 7+, and tried both revalidate and repaint (placed a paint() method that included only add(page);, is that correct?) without success..

Comment: Adding MenuBar is not the issue. And for "(placed a paint(...) method that included only add(page);, is that correct?", where had you used paint() method, are you overriding this method of some component, then don't use paint() rather override paintComponent(...) method

Comment: You sir, have my thanks for in eternity!!
I changed my method to this:
     public void setPage(JPanel p) {
  System.out.println("Set page");
  remove(page);
  page = p;
  add(page);
  revalidate();
  repaint();
 }

and it works :). Thanks for the awesome lesson!

Comment: @MarkTielemans :Your Welcome and Glad to help you on this. Keep Smiling :-)

Answer (score 2):

When changing the component hierarchy of a visible component you have to validate the hierachy in order to make your changes visible. See [JavaDoc of the remove() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29):

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to reflect the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I was convinced that happened with remove and add automatically! I have however no idea how to validate the hierarchy again. Could you help me out with that?